# Toast Notifier is not working, Have i done something wrong?

Tags: python, pip, toast

First off thanks for taking the time to read this:

I am currently trying to get ToastNotifier working in python in MU.
I have imported ToastNotifier from win10toast as such :

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
```

I have the created this function:

```
def notifacation():
    toast = ToastNotifier()
    Title = "Notifacation"
    message = "Hello from Ben Colledge"
    icon = "a.ico"
    length = 30
    toast.show_toast(title, message, icon_path=icon, duration=length)
```

And then called the function like so :

```
notifacation()
```

I then run the code and it give me this error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\puzzl\mu_code\notifacation.py", line 1, in module
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win10toast'

I have then gone to https://pypi.org/project/win10toast/ and downloaded win10toast yet nothing happened

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: try to install it trought command prompt `pip install win10toast`

Comment: I have tried this and it says the following                                                                        'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem but then I figured out this works best

```
python.exe -m pip install win10toast
```

I ran this code and it still has a problem not, although, the same one. Now the bug would be that in the line that has the method.

```
toast.show_toast(title, message, icon_path=icon, duration=length)
```

The problem is that 'title' is undefined. The variable that you assigned was named 'Title'. Since Python is case-sensitive, 'title' is an undifined variable. this is what the line should look like now:

```
toast.show_toast(Title, message, icon_path=icon, duration=length)
```

Yay! It works now!

Comment: In fact, I used this method to install win10toast myself